# Stop listening AngularFireAuth when Offline

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

On my Angular app, I use this to know the status (source: https://medium.com/@balramchavan/detecting-internet-connection-status-in-angular-application-ng-connection-service-1fa8add3b975)

```
constructor(private connectionService: ConnectionService) {
    this.connectionService.monitor().subscribe(isConnected => {
      if (isConnected) {
        // ONLINE
      }
      else {
        // OFFLINE
      }
    })
  }
```

For my firebase repository, to avoid console error flooding, I have:

```
constructor(
    protected afs: AngularFirestore,
    protected connectionService: ConnectionService,
    protected collectionName: string,
  ) {
    this.connectionService.monitor().subscribe(status => {
      if (status) {
        afs.firestore.enableNetwork();
      }
      else {
        afs.firestore.disableNetwork();
      }
    })


  }
```

But I didnt find the way to do the same with the Auth Firebase Service:

```
constructor(
    private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    protected connectionService: ConnectionService,
  ) {
    this.connectionService.monitor().subscribe(status => {
      if (status) {
        angularFireAuth.//Start listening
      }
      else {
        angularFireAuth.//Stop listening
      }
    })
  }
```

So I get this error multiple times:

> POST https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=XXX
> net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Do you know how to handle it?

Thanks

Comment: did you trace which specific functionality causes this error? it might be just one being token refresh, which you could just put on condition as well. There seems to be no other methods that would rely on open network connection with Firebase Auth

Comment: I tried, but I didnt find any significant information which could help :(